# Using Define for throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, throw

Currently, I am refactoring some old project which has been written by somebody of our ex-workers. I have encountered with wrapping of throwing exception with a define.

Something like that:

```
#define THROWIT(msg) throw common::error(msg)
```

Example from the code:

```
#define THROW_FD_ERROR( fd, op )\
throw common::error_fd( errno,\
    __ERR_FD_API_3\
    .arg( fd )\
    .arg( op )\
    .arg( strerror(errno) ),\
    __FILE__,\
    __LINE__ )
```

I can see some benefits of it, but they not so huge for me to do it in a such way. 
Anyway, is it a common technic? 
In you opinion what advantages can be gained from it? 
Are you using defines for throwing exception? 
if yes what the purpose of that ?

UPD: add define from the code

UPD2: Thanks all for your answers. I've decided to take out all macros. In purpose of debuging  I will extend the base error class with backtrace info, in my opinion it is better than just using standart defines for file and line.

Comment: There is no advantage in a macro for this. However, I commonly define a boolean `fail` function. It supports the perl-idiomatic "do or die" notation, which is short and visually recognizable without being noisy.

Comment: It's really opinion based but I can't see any single benefit for a #DEFINE. If I really need some complex logic (for example to collect data to attach to exception to be thrown) then I'd use a function...

Comment: _'Anyway, is it a common technic?'_ Certainly not!

Comment: in your example having a macro like this is pointless, unless it has some debugging advantage like making use of __LINE__. shortening the number of characters also hides useful information like type type of exception being thrown.

Comment: I've added define from the code.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the preprocessor is only used if you need a preprocessor-specific feature, like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__`. This macro does nothing a function cannot and therefore it is quite atypical and bad.

Comment: See update, in my opinion it just to simplify typing plus some debuging information. The code has defines for each type of possibly exception and they are widely used across the code. So in your opinion is it worth to refactor such way of throwing into "standart way" or just leave as it?

Answer (score 3):

The Macro as presented doesn't have a whole lot of benefit.

However, a macro *can* have a benefit if you want to include file name, function name and line numbers in the exception message:

```
#define POSSIBLY_USEFUL_THROWIT(msg) throw common::error(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, msg)
```

Oh, and `THROWIT` is a horrible name for this.

---

Alf highlights a good point:

> You can use a macro to collect the information, and it's the only way
>   to do it. However, tying that to the throwing of an exception is a
>   conflation of responsibilities. This means you would need separate
>   such macros for logging, UI message, and so on. A single macro would
>   be far preferable.

I think what he means is having something like this:

```
// Construct new temporary object source_line_info
#define CURRENT_SRC_LINE_INFO() common::source_line_info(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)
```

and then using it like this:

```
throw common::error(CURRENT_SRC_LINE_INFO(), msg);
```

to have only that part macro'fied that really needs it.

Personally, I would then prefer to have an additional macro like

```
#define THROW_COMMON_ERROR(...)  throw common::error(CURRENT_SRC_LINE_INFO(), ...
```

Because *if* I'm going to have a "macro call" on multiple lines, I might just as well make it as short and as centralized as possible, even if that means introducing another macro.

Comment: You can use a macro to collect the information, and it's the only way to do it. However, tying that to the throwing of an exception is a conflation of responsibilities. This means you would need separate such macros for logging, UI message, and so on. A single macro would be far preferable.

Comment: it's just an example, code contains macro for each type of exception. THROW_ERROR, THROW_FD_ERROR and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't. Bad. It makes the code harder to understand and isn't all that shorter to type.

If you really must, use a function. But I don't think you really must, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages are that there are less characters to type and that you could change the throw declaration (like throwing another type) at a single point (the macro). However, you could also use a usual function instead of a macro. Using macros where a function can do exactly the same is considered no good practice because of the problems macros have (like no scoping and possible pollution of other files that include the macro defining header. Macros are at most a tool to be used when no other language feature can do the same thing and you desperately need it.

Thus, I would not consider this good practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's better to use inline functions in C++. Macro's are substituted without compiler's checks. Preprocessor macros should be used where no other way to do the task.